# Seeking in-depth coverage of this French defense sideline

Tags: opening, french-defense

```
[FEN ""]
    1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Nc6
```

I am seeking high-level, in-depth coverage of the above line.

I was able to find small coverage in ECO C and liked what I saw there.

Is there any book/article that thoroughly deals with this line?

I would give more info, but I am not a French player. Still, I find the line very fun, hence the question.

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, this variation is called the Guimard variation of the french defense

Comment: @Scounged I thought the Guimard variation was 3. Nd2 Nc6, not 3. Nc3 Nc6.

Comment: This article coins the name "Rozentalis variation": https://www.chesspublishing.com/content/2/oct05.htm#roz

Comment: @bof Ah, you're right. I didn't pay enough attention, and failed to realize that the Guimard is a response to the Tarrasch variation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a 12-page chapter on this position in Cristoph Wisneski's "Play 1...Nc6!: A complete chess opening repertoire for Black."  In that book it's reached via 1.e4 Nc6, 2.d4 d5, 3.Nc3 e6.  More generally you're probably more likely to see this discussed in books on the Nimzowitsch defense (with d5, not e5) rather than French defense books.

Comment: +1 and accepted. I doubt anyone else will come up with an answer, as the line seems obscure. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There's also a chapter on it in "Dangerous Weapons: French" by John Watson from Everyman (2007)